# How do i disable a D#+ Command To not show for users who dont have certain permissions?

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

how do i disable a D#+ Command to not show for users who don't have specific permissions such as Administrator, Or Owner?

a reply would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to hide a command from someone who should not have access to it is with attribution.

```cs
[SlashCommand("hello", "hello world")]
[RequirePermissions(DSharpPlus.Permissions.Administrator)] //Must have admin perm to see/use
public static async Task HelloWorld(InteractionContext ctx)
{
    await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
      new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder().WithContent("Hello, World!"));
}
```

You can change the attribution to any of the permissions found in [DSharpPlus.Permissions](https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/api/DSharpPlus.Permissions.html)

You can also use roles for this as well:

```cs
[SlashCommand("hello", "hello world")]
[RequireRoles(RoleCheckMode.Any, new ulong[] { 99999 })] // must have role with ID 99999
public static async Task HelloWorld(InteractionContext ctx)
{
    await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
      new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder().WithContent("Hello, World!"));
}
```

[RoleCheckMode](https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/api/DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.Attributes.RoleCheckMode.html) can be used to define parameters for when you have multiple roles involved, and you can find more about this attribution [here](https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/api/DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.Attributes.RequireRolesAttribute.-ctor.html)